# Compile-time action in R

Tags: r, compile-time

Suppose I have a file `foo.R` and a list of regular expressions in `rex.txt`.
If I put

```
rex <- paste(read.table("rex.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]],collapse="|")
```

into `foo.R`, then the variable `rex` is initialized correctly when I load `foo.R` using `library()`. 
The same happens when I compile `foo.R` to `foo.Rc` and load the latter, which is good.

What I want, however, is that the literal value of variable `rex` is included in `foo.Rc` (when I call [`cmpfile`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/compiler/html/compile.html)), i.e., when `foo.Rc` is loaded, variable `rex` is initialised from whatever was in `rex.txt` at compilation time, similar to Emacs Lisp [`eval-when-compile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html) (this way I don't have to copy `rex.txt` to the server where I actually run `foo.Rc`).

Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at compiliation time" here?

Comment: @Dason: When I call `cmpfile`. The bottom line is that I don't want to have to copy `rex.txt` to the server.

Comment: I think you'll have to modify `foo.R` just before calling `cmpfile`, changing the line you mention to *the result of* `paste("rex <-", deparse(paste(read.table(...))))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify `foo.R` *just before compilation*, as shown below.

Test data:

```
text <- '
doSomething()
rex <- paste(read.table("rex.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]],collapse="|")
doOtherStuff()
'

writeLines(text,"foo.R")
```

Code:

```
foo <- readLines("foo.R")

pattern <- "^rex\\s*<-.*$"

eval(parse(text=grep(pattern, foo, value=TRUE))[[1]])

newtext <- gsub(pattern, paste("rex <-",deparse(rex)), foo)

writeLines(newtext,"foo.R")
```

Note that `eval()` will execute the line `rex <- ...` to create this object in the global environment, so that `deparse()` can find it. I'm also assuming you only have one line matching the `pattern` used.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to Ferdinand.kraft's, but I would recommend parse/substitute instead of regexps. This should be a bit more flexible if you need to do this for multiple variables in a file.

```
substitutedFile <- "foo-sub.R"

#save rex into an environment
a <- new.env()    
local(envir=a, {
  rex <- paste(read.table("rex.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]],collapse="|")    
})

#Substitute variables from a into foo.R and write it back out
lines <- lapply(parse("foo.R"), function(expr) {
  deparse(eval(substitute(substitute(expr, a), list(expr=expr)))) 
})    
writeLines(paste(lines, collapse="\n"),substitutedFile)

cmpfile(substitutedFile)
```

Comment: This is wrong. I get `"1:4 <- paste(read.table(\"rex.txt\", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]], " "    collapse = \"|\")"` in `lines`, using `local(envir=a, rex <- 1:4)`.

Comment: Are you running my code on itself? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: No, I'm running your code on my test `foo.R`, from my answer. Did you test your answer?